# MySQLdb / Python: Can't insert certain characters in the db

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, utf-8, mysql-python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'django_user', 'haha123', 'mydb')
cur = conn.cursor()

f = open('/home/kave/projects/cb/database/country_code_drupal_nov_2011.txt')

cur.execute("INSERT INTO myapp_app_currency (currency) VALUES ('USD - $'),('EUR - €'), ('GBP - £'), ('CAD - $'), ('AUD - $'), ('BRL - R$');")
```

For some reason I can insert this data successfully into my database, however two entries get corrupted.

```
EUR - € becomes EUR - â‚¬
GBP - £ becomes GBP - Â£
```

I thought I had set it as utf8 and it should roll, why there a problem only with those two characters?

Comment: Incidentally, you should probably split the symbol and the description into separate columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the charset when connecting to the database:

```python
conn = MySQLdb.connect('host', 'usr', 'pass', 'db', charset='utf8')
```

When you use `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the document, it only applies to the source code document, *not* to what it performs.

Comment: that worked. Thanks. Could you elaborate what you mean by `actual source`?

Comment: I mean that it specifies the encoding of the source code document. See [PEP 0263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for more info.